# Конвертировать big int number в base64

Tags: javascript, node.js

Как конвертировать big int в base64 (не строку, а число)?

Пример: `215968764` → `DN9r_A`

Comment: @Doofy вроде всё понятно, пример есть. В питоне можно декодировать в одну строчку `int.from_bytes(base64.b64decode('DN9r/A=='), 'big')`

Comment: Единственное, что действительно не помешало бы уточнить — желаемое поведение для чисел, размер которых в бинарном виде не равен 4 байтам (меньше 16777216 и больше 4294967295)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Судя по примеру это base64 от 32-битного Big-Endian и поскольку в тегах стоит `nodejs` будем пользоваться `Buffer`:

```js
function number2base64(n) {
    // тут стоит проверить, что n < 2^32
    const b = Buffer.alloc(4);
    b.writeUInt32BE(n);         // записываем число в буфер
    return b.toString('base64') // получаем base64 и преобразуем в base64url
        .slice(0, 6)            // убираем паддинг
        .replace(/\+/g, '-')    // '+' → '-'
        .replace(/\//g, '_');   // '/' → '_'
}
```

Вообще-то настоящий base64 для этого числа выглядит так: `DN9r/A==`, а то что в примере обычно называют [base64url](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications)

Comment: спасибо, это то что мне нужно

Answer (score 1):

В языке JavaScript существуют две функции, для кодирования и декодирования данных в/из формат Base64 соответственно:

- btoa()
- atob()

`btoa()` принимает только строку, но тем не менее туда можно передать и число, но `atob()` всегда вернёт строку.

```
btoa(15) === btoa("15")
```

[Источник](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Base64)

Comment: это совсем не то что мне нужно

Answer (score 0):

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/246813/12300532)

```js
const Base64 = {
  _keyStr: "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=",
  encode: function(input) {
    input = new String(input);
    var output = "";
    var chr1, chr2, chr3, enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
    var i = 0;

    input = Base64._utf8_encode(input);

    while (i < input.length) {

      chr1 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
      chr2 = input.charCodeAt(i++);
      chr3 = input.charCodeAt(i++);

      enc1 = chr1 >> 2;
      enc2 = ((chr1 & 3) << 4) | (chr2 >> 4);
      enc3 = ((chr2 & 15) << 2) | (chr3 >> 6);
      enc4 = chr3 & 63;

      if (isNaN(chr2)) {
        enc3 = enc4 = 64;
      } else if (isNaN(chr3)) {
        enc4 = 64;
      }

      output = output +
        this._keyStr.charAt(enc1) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc2) +
        this._keyStr.charAt(enc3) + this._keyStr.charAt(enc4);

    }

    return output;
  },
  decode: function(input) {
    var output = "";
    var chr1, chr2, chr3;
    var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4;
    var i = 0;

    input = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");

    while (i < input.length) {

      enc1 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
      enc2 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
      enc3 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
      enc4 = this._keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));

      chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);
      chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);
      chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;

      output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr1);

      if (enc3 != 64) {
        output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr2);
      }
      if (enc4 != 64) {
        output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr3);
      }

    }

    output = Base64._utf8_decode(output);
    
    if (isAN(+output)) {
      output = +output;
    }

    return output;

  },
  _utf8_encode: function(string) {
    string = string.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");
    var utftext = "";

    for (var n = 0; n < string.length; n++) {

      var c = string.charCodeAt(n);

      if (c < 128) {
        utftext += String.fromCharCode(c);
      } else if ((c > 127) && (c < 2048)) {
        utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 6) | 192);
        utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
      } else {
        utftext += String.fromCharCode((c >> 12) | 224);
        utftext += String.fromCharCode(((c >> 6) & 63) | 128);
        utftext += String.fromCharCode((c & 63) | 128);
      }

    }

    return utftext;
  },
  _utf8_decode: function(utftext) {
    var string = "";
    var i = 0;
    var c = c1 = c2 = 0;

    while (i < utftext.length) {

      c = utftext.charCodeAt(i);

      if (c < 128) {
        string += String.fromCharCode(c);
        i++;
      } else if ((c > 191) && (c < 224)) {
        c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i + 1);
        string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 31) << 6) | (c2 & 63));
        i += 2;
      } else {
        c2 = utftext.charCodeAt(i + 1);
        c3 = utftext.charCodeAt(i + 2);
        string += String.fromCharCode(((c & 15) << 12) | ((c2 & 63) << 6) | (c3 & 63));
        i += 3;
      }

    }

    return string;
  }

}

function isAN(value) {
  return (value instanceof Number||typeof value === 'number') && !isNaN(value);
}

const num = 123;

const encodedString = Base64.encode(num);
console.log(encodedString);

const decodedString = Base64.decode(encodedString);
console.log(decodedString, typeof decodedString);
```

Comment: у числа немного другая кодировка, попробуйте посмотреть мой пример